# How to parse the data in <pre> tag using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

when I am trying to scrape the data from the following website

url = https://bedbathandbeyond.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/2009-en_us/1061083288/reviews.djs?format=embeddedhtml&page=4&scrollToTop=true

I got this from bedbathbeyond website and if I use request and beautifulsoup, I can't get anything. Why is that?

code:

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
soup.find_all('span', class_ = 'BVRRReviewAbbreviatedText')
```

the return value is empty: []

Comment: That's because the HTML is inside an AJAX call, so BeautifulSoup won't be able to parse content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [`js2py`](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py), since `materials` object contains several keys (`BVRRRatingSummarySourceID`, `BVRRSecondaryRatingSummarySourceID` and `BVRRSourceID`) and getting the HTML from its values with regex would be much harder in case you need it all.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import js2py
import requests

r = requests.get('https://bedbathandbeyond.ugc.bazaarvoice.com/2009-en_us/1061083288/reviews.djs?format=embeddedhtml')

pattern = (r'var'
           r'\s+'
           r'materials'
           r'\s*=\s*'
           r'{"BVRRRatingSummarySourceID".*}')

js_materials = re.search(pattern, r.text).group()
obj = js2py.eval_js(js_materials).to_dict()
html = obj['BVRRSourceID']
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
spans = soup.select('span.BVRRReviewAbbreviatedText')
```

```
>>> len(spans)
5
```

In the example below I only used the HTML under the `BVRRSourceID` key, but you can use the entire HTML by join the values together:

```
html = ''.join(obj.values())
```

Don't forget to install `js2py`: `pip install js2py` and `pip install lxml` if you want to use `lxml` parser.

Comment: Even tho I didn't quite understand some parts of the answer, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can read about regular expressions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Answer (score -1):

You could use selenium webdriver in order to get the html content that you are interested. For example,

```
from selenium import webdriver


def get_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(url)

    time.sleep(5)
    html_content = driver.page_source.strip()
    return html_content
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. after saving the result to a variable, let say "a=get_html(url)", then I tried to parse it using Beautifulsoup: soup = Beautifulsoup(a,'lxml'), then 'soup.find_all('span', class = 'BVRRReviewText'), still can not retrieve anything. Why is that?